# Create a dictionary with a fixed set of keys from reading text file in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, readfile

**Input:**
- A text file that contains 3 lines:

```
"Thank you
binhnguyen
2010-09-12
I want to say thank you to all of you."
```

**Output:**
I want to create a dictionary with fixed keys: *'title', 'name', 'date', 'feedback'* that stores 4 lines in the file above respectively.

> > {'title': 'Thank you', 'name': 'binhnguyen', 'date': '2010-09-12
> >     ', 'feedback': 'I want to say thank you to all of you.'}

Thank you so much

Comment: Please update the question with the code you have tried.

Comment: [Here's a hint](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/#examples) for `dict` comprehension..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can basically define a list of keys and match them with lines.

Example:

```
key_list = ["title","name","date","feedback"]
text = [line.replace("\n","").replace("\"","")  for line in open("text.txt","r").readlines()]
dictionary = {}
for index in range(len(text)):
    dictionary[key_list[index]] = text[index]

print(dictionary)
```

Output:

```
{'title': 'Thank you', 'name': 'binhnguyen', 'date': '2010-09-12', 'feedback': 'I want to say thank you to all of you.'}
```

Comment: replace ``for index in range(len(text))`` with ``for line in text``. And instead of calling it ``text`` call it ``lines``

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Given `file.txt` where the file is and the format is the one described on the question this would be the code:

```
path = r"./file.txt"

content = open(path, "r").read().replace("\"", "")
lines = content.split("\n")

dict_ = {
    'title': lines[0],
    'name': lines[1],
    'date': lines[2],
    'feedback': lines[3]
}
print(dict_)
```

Comment: Remember to close your file (`content`), else use `with open(...) as f: lines = f.readlines()`; and no need for the raw string in your path.

Comment: May I know why replace("\"", "") is used?

Comment: Because your text file contains ".